# Как запушить в массив один раз после окончания цикла, а не с каждым пробегом цикла?

Tags: javascript

```
let city = [
    {c:'Nashville',state:'TN',latitudes:36.17,longitudes:-86.78},
    {c:'New York',state:'NY',latitudes:40.71,longitudes:-74.00},
    {c:'Atlanta',state:'GA',latitudes:33.75,longitudes:-84.39},
    {c:'Denver',state:'CO',latitudes:39.74,longitudes:-104.98},
    {c:'Seattle',state:'WA',latitudes:47.61,longitudes:-122.33},
    {c:'Los Angeles',state:'CA',latitudes:34.05,longitudes:-118.24},
    {c:'Memphis',state:'TN',latitudes:35.15,longitudes:-90.05},
];
function cityName(city){
    let cc =[];
        for(let i = 0; i < city.length; i++){
            cc.push(city[i].c);
            console.log(cc)
        }
}
cityName(city)
```

как вывести результат в консоль после всего пробега цикла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let data = [
  {c:'Nashville',state:'TN',latitudes:36.17,longitudes:-86.78},
  {c:'New York',state:'NY',latitudes:40.71,longitudes:-74.00},
  {c:'Atlanta',state:'GA',latitudes:33.75,longitudes:-84.39},
  {c:'Denver',state:'CO',latitudes:39.74,longitudes:-104.98},
  {c:'Seattle',state:'WA',latitudes:47.61,longitudes:-122.33},
  {c:'Los Angeles',state:'CA',latitudes:34.05,longitudes:-118.24},
  {c:'Memphis',state:'TN',latitudes:35.15,longitudes:-90.05},
];

function cityNames(cities){
  return cities.map(i => i.c);
}

console.log(cityNames(data));
```